# How to use sudo like ubuntu in docker alpine linux

Tags: dockerfile, zsh, alpine-linux, oh-my-zsh

I'm building my own Linux docker image using Alpine Linux.

First, I wanted to improve the security of my Linux like Ubuntu by installing sudo.

```
RUN echo "root:$ROOT_PASSWORD" | chpasswd
RUN apk add sudo

RUN adduser -D myuser
RUN echo "myuser:$MYUSER_PASSWORD" | chpasswd
RUN chmod u+s /bin/busybox
USER myuser
WORKDIR /home/myuser
```

And to use sudo in the dockerfile, I stopped prompting for the sudo password for a while.

```
RUN sed -i "s|root ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL|root ALL=NOPASSWD: ALL\nmyuser ALL=NOPASSWD: ALL|g" /etc/sudoers
```

Next, I installed zsh, and additionally installed and set oh-my-zsh.

```
USER myuser
WORKDIR /home/myuser

RUN sudo apk add zsh
RUN sudo sed -i "s|/bin/ash|/bin/zsh|g" /etc/passwd
RUN sudo apk add git
RUN sudo sh -c "$(wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/master/tools/install.sh -O -)"
```

Now, if you build the docker file and connect using docker attach container_name, root is set to oh-my-zsh, but myuser is not set.

It seems that it was installed in /root in the process of doing sudo.

Ubuntu was normally installed in the general user area when "sudo apt install zsh" was executed with a general user account.

Is there any way to solve this?

Here is my dockerfile.

```
ROM alpine:latest

ARG TITLE="skeleton_linux"
ARG ROOT_PASSWORD="dummy123"
ARG MYUSER_PASSWORD="dummy123"

LABEL title=$TITLE
LABEL version="1.0.0"

ENV TZ=Asia/Seoul

RUN apk update
RUN apk upgrade

RUN echo "root:$ROOT_PASSWORD" | chpasswd

RUN apk add sudo
RUN apk add nano

RUN sed -i "s|root ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL|root ALL=NOPASSWD: ALL\nmyuser ALL=NOPASSWD: ALL|g" /etc/sudoers

RUN adduser -D myuser
RUN echo "nineright:$MYUSER_PASSWORD" | chpasswd
RUN chmod u+s /bin/busybox
USER myuser
WORKDIR /home/myuser

RUN sudo apk add zsh
RUN sudo sed -i "s|/bin/ash|/bin/zsh|g" /etc/passwd
RUN sudo apk add git
RUN sudo sh -c "$(wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/master/tools/install.sh -O -)"
```

Comment: If anything, giving the user running the container a passwordless sudo right is a huge security hole calling for a disaster to happen, not a security improvement. If you want to run something as root, run `docker exec -ti --user root <uid-of-container> ash`. The fact that the container's default user is not root as defined in the `USER` attribute doesn't mean you cannot override it when running or attaching to a (existing) container.